# Volley Object request Returning 0

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-studio, android-volley

I Have a Remote Database that contains 6 rows.
Here's my code, I put it in List so that i can get the size,
But it's always returning 0.

```
public List<Comments> getComments() {
        final List<Comments> commentsData = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                showUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("poi");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Comments current = new Comments();
                        current.image = "drawable://" + R.drawable.juandirection_placeholder;
                        current.title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        current.comment = jsonObject.getString("comment");
                        current.date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                        current.rating = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("rating"));
                        commentsData.add(current);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        VolleyHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
        return commentsData;
    }
```

I need the size for some use.
Why is it always returning zero?
I even tried adding a counter++ inside for loop.
But when i get the value of the counter its still zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonObjectRequest run on a background thread. That's why you getting the list size 0. you must work into the `public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {}` function .

Exmp.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("poi");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Comments current = new Comments();
                    current.image = "drawable://" + R.drawable.juandirection_placeholder;
                    current.title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                    current.comment = jsonObject.getString("comment");
                    current.date = jsonObject.getString("date");
                    current.rating = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("rating"));
                    commentsData.add(current);
                }

                // **you may call function and pass the list value to update your ui component. you will get the real size of list here.**

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: so that's why everything i tried returns zero because its running on background. One question, is JsonObjectRequest the best choice for something like this? like getting values for database? is there much more better libraries than volley?

Comment: As far as i know Volley is the best and also google promoting to use this library. link : http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Also, whatever you use for pulling data from remote database, you must run a background thead(i mean asynchronous thread).

Comment: Well. I'm having a problem setting the adapter in recycler view. Because at first i Need the rows return from the database. Second i need the rows because I have a recyclerview with multiple layouts.

Comment: Is it possible that if i use asyncTask can I get the rows during the JSobObjectRequest?

Comment: if you check carefully after the for loop in the onResponse method , your have the list of data from your database. so, your number of rows will be `int row = commentsData.size();`
you can do whatever you want after getting the data.

Comment: But after getting this row. Im still working inside the onResponse right?  Like. Setting the recyclerview adapter inside onresponse??

Comment: yes , the problem is , ui componect can't be tauched without UI thread. You need to do this action by calling runOnUIThread(Runnable);
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); // set the adapter here.
            }
        });
`

Comment: Ill just put runOnUiThread inside onresponse then im good to go?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.. :) Ill try this tomorrow. Been doing this all day. Thanks so much..

Comment: I put my arrays and adapter inside on response but the static value of textview doesn't show. also the ripple effect of recyclerview has gone..

Comment: i actually can't get your answer. what do mean by static value ? do you mean this -> 

`String staticValue = textView.getText();`

but i don't know why your ripple effect don't work. it's not related with volley.

Comment: You most welcome. you can give a +1 vote if you wish.