# Accessing data inside onResponse Volley overriting the text: Android

Tags: android, json, textview, android-volley

I am having an app that displays the list of several companies and their branches. I need to display the opening timing of the companies and their branches. I am trying to fetch my data from the server using volley,

```
String url = context.getString(site_url) + "branch_time.cfc?method=branchtime&branchid=" + bid;


  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response) {

         String MON_O = "";
         String TUE_O = "";
         String WED_O = "";


      try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
     JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("DATA");

    final int numberOfItemsInBranch = result.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItemsInBranch; i++) {
    JSONArray companyData = result.optJSONArray(i);

     MON_O = companyData.getString(3);
     TUE_O = companyData.getString(4);
     WED_O = companyData.getString(5);

      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
 },
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "Sorry, couldn't fetch business hours for" + companyTradeName + "Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
      requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

I need to use the above value for setting the text into the textviews such as,

```
      timeStatus.setText(MON_O);
      currentStatus.setText(TUE_O);
```

The issue I am facing is when I set the text for my text views inside the response method, it displays only the data in the last text view for the companies having multiple branches.

If I set the data after the requestQueue.add(stringRequest); I am getting my response as null.

I don't want to use callback here. Is there any other way to achieve this. Please help me as I am stuck in this for weeks. 
I have already gone through many links like,

- [How to access data outside onResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44392186/how-to-access-data-outside-onresponse)
- [volley- How do I return the ArrayList from OnResponse Method In Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558566/volley-how-do-i-return-the-arraylist-from-onresponse-method-in-volley)
- [Volley Object request Returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721683/volley-object-request-returning-0)

also several other links, but couldn't fix my issue. Please help.

**EDIT:**

My JSON response from the server,

```
{"COLUMNS":  ["TIMEID","BRANCHID","COMPANYID","MON_O","TUE_O","WED_O","THU_O","FRI_O","SAT_O","SUN_O","MON_C","TUE_C","WED_C","THU_C","FRI_C","SAT_C","SUN_C","CREATDATE"],"DATA":[[507,1202,1187,"08:00","08:00","08:00","08:00","08:00","Closed","Closed","16:30","16:30","16:30","16:30","16:30","Closed","Closed","June, 02 2017 13:18:42"]]}
```

The issue is here is the response from the server is coming fine but when I am looping the data, only the last value is getting updated. Is there any way to use the result from the response method outside without using the callback. If I get the response value out of the response method I think it can fix my issue.

NOTE: I cannot use a listview here. All I have are set of 7 text views which are looping in case of multiple branches.

Comment: If you want a nice explanation and use of volleyRequest [Please Reffer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45636713/7230266)

Comment: where are setting the text i.e., **timeStatus.setText(MON_O);**.. inside onResponse or outside?

Comment: I am getting my response from the volley. Only issue is I want to use that response out of the onResponse method.

Comment: @Raghavendra I want to set it outside the onResponse.

Comment: You have to set it when you get the response only right. Either put all the setText.. in one method and call that method in onResponse

Comment: yes... after I get the response I want to set the text to my textview

Comment: Actually when I did the exact thing... put all my setText in one method an called them from onResponse. But the issue in that is when I am having multiple branches and it loops, only the last branches details are displayed

Comment: Then you have to prepare a Pojo class and prepare a List of those and use that

Comment: Can u please suggest how can I do that?

Comment: Post your json response

Comment: Added the Json response. Please see the updated question.

Comment: u want only MON_O, TUE_O, WED_O values?

Comment: I want all the values. Did not add all of them in the question.

Comment: Looks like u need to use Listview/recyclerview if u want to show List of DATA response.

Comment: Isn't there any other way to make it work, since I don't want to change the entire thing now.

Comment: @devgeek you don't know how much data will come in the response. If you want to show all the data you have to use Listview

Comment: I want to show all the data. All the data in the JSON response needs to be shown. I need to show the timings of the 7 days in a week